# Can CORS conflict in any way with bearer authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, backend

Here's Program.cs:
I have tried a many times to change the order of the middleware, I know about the rule in what order it should be located, but still no results.Please advise me of my possible mistakes, I have been trying to correct them for two days now.

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithMethods("POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT")
            .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600));
        });
});
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });

    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value!))
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICloudStorage, GoogleCloudStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opts =>
{
    opts.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:CircleConnection"]);
    opts.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
});
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
builder.Services.Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(opts =>
{
    opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("^$", "swagger/index.html"));
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
SeedDatabase();
app.Run();
```

[image: Error]

Comment: try this one out

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true));
            });

Comment: @HuSaad That's terrible advice! You should never allow all origins with credentials. Doing so opens the door to cross-origin attacks. See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Comment: @Dmitriy Do not follow HuSaad's advice. Fix your problem some other way.

Comment: I agree as well u should mention the origin domain update as follow

 .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
.SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true));

make sure to change the origin when production takes to place

assuming the website on localhost:3000

Comment: Calling `.SetIsOriginAllowed((hosts) => true))` consists in allowing all origins, so same problem. Don't do that.

Comment: You know how fix this issue more better?